# returning an ajax response

Tags: javascript

I have researched this for several days now and I just can't get anything to work. I am using php to query a MySQL database. I'm getting a response via ajax but I need to be able to use the response. For example I need to take the response multiplied by 5. I can show the response in my HTML but I can't do anything to make my script read it as a number. I've tried parseInt Number() and so on. The code as I have it returns the correct number but I can't use it. Here is my code.

```
$('#checkStockButton').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "mainApple.php",
    data: "",
    async: false,
    success: function(result) { 
      stockPriceApple = result;
      parseInt(stockPriceApple,10)
      $('#responsecontainerApple').html(stockPriceApple);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `parseInt()` _returns_ a number.

Comment: You need to assign the result of `parseInt` to a number, or else your code isn't doing anything.

Comment: Also note, `stockPriceApple` is an implicit global variable here.

Comment: Ok Thanks I hadn't noticed that. And yes it is a global variable.

Comment: Can you post the response `result` please?

Comment: I get a number like 15724.

Comment: my php is doing what its supposed to and I'm getting the number back using echoand that is all working

Answer (score 3):

parseInt returns a number, so you need to do this:

```
    stockPriceApple = parseInt(result,10);
    $('#responsecontainerApple').html(stockPriceApple);
```

As the content of your success function

Comment: Ok I added this and now I have nothing returning. Its like when I try to make it recognize a number it doesn't show anything.

Comment: @wunruh, are you sure result is even a number or number-string? Are you sure you are getting what you are expecting?

Comment: @wunruh can you share an example of result?

Comment: I get a number like 15724

Answer (score 1):

if you want to read data into your success function, you first have to do: `json_encode($result)` at server-side (PHP)  and then decode it in your java-script success function like: `var str = JSON.parse(result); alert str[0]`

for example: server side php

```
    function sendjson(){
            $data=array(0=>'zero', 1=>'one');
            echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

and client side, in your ajax success function:

```
    success: function(html){
                var str = JSON.parse(html);
                alert(str[0]);
            }
```

or using associative array:
serverside php:

```
function sendjson(){
    $data=array('firstvalueofarray'=>'zero', 'secondvalueofarray'=>'one');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and clientside:

```
     success: function(html){
                var str = JSON.parse(html);
                alert(str.firstvalueofarray);
            }
```

in both cases the alert box will display 'zero'

Comment: Ok what is the echo str[0] part for? This is what I've been trying to wrap my head around and nothing I do involving JSON will work for me.

Comment: @wunruh this was just to show, that you may also work with arrays, in case you need to send multiple data variables. You can even send associative arrays, e.g.: PHP server-side: $data=array(0=>'zero', 1=>'one'); echo json_encode($data); and on the client-side: success: function(html){var str = JSON.parse(html);alert(str[0]);
    }